# Getting org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, rest, thymeleaf

I am new to Spring boot, so I am facing a few errors.

I am inserting a few user inputs from an HTML page into the DB. I am able to insert the data into the DB using the POST method. Then from the DB I want to read those details and display using GET method of REST API. But I am getting the following exception:

```
2023-08-26 12:20:28.125 ERROR 15292 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-3] Exception processing template "users": Error resolving template [users], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [users], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Following are my Controller code:

```
package com.forms.demo.htmlExample.controller;


import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import com.forms.demo.htmlExample.model.User;
import com.forms.demo.htmlExample.repo.UserRepository;
import com.forms.demo.htmlExample.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService service;
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        
        return "index";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return service.getUsers();
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String userRegistration(@ModelAttribute User user, Model model) {
        
        System.out.println(user.toString());
        
        System.out.println(user.getFname());
        System.out.println(user.getLname());
        System.out.println(user.getEmail());
        System.out.println(user.getGender());
        System.out.println(user.getDob());
        System.out.println(user.getGender());
        model.addAttribute("firstname", user.getFname());
        model.addAttribute("lastname", user.getLname());
        model.addAttribute("email", user.getEmail());
        
        repo.save(user);
        
        model.addAttribute("message", user.getEmail() + " inserted");
        
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

Following is my service class code:

```
package com.forms.demo.htmlExample.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.forms.demo.htmlExample.model.User;
import com.forms.demo.htmlExample.repo.UserRepository;

@Service
public class UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userRepo.findAll();
    }
    
}
```

Following is my repo class:

```
package com.forms.demo.htmlExample.repo;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.forms.demo.htmlExample.model.User;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

Following is the code of my entity class:

```
package com.forms.demo.htmlExample.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="user_data")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private String email;
    private String passwd;
    private String dob;
    private String gender;

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }
    
    public String getPasswd() {
        return passwd;
    }

    public void setPasswd(String passwd) {
        this.passwd = passwd;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }
    
    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }
    
    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }
    
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    
    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    
    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }   
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [fname=" + fname + ", lname=" + lname + ", email=" + email + ", passwd=" + passwd + ", dob=" + dob
                + ", gender=" + gender + "]";
    }


}
```

I am sending the following URL to fetch the data from the DB:

```
http://localhost:8080/users
```

And for this I am getting the error message in the web page:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Aug 26 12:20:28 IST 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
```

In the console I am getting the following exception - org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException

Please let me know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller class is currently a Web Controller and not a REST Controller. When you call the `users` endpoint Spring Boot is trying to find a Thymeleaf template named `users.html` under default location `<classpath>/templates`. It is not there because you don't want to show a page but just a JSON response with all existing users.

**Solution**

To achieve this add the `@ResponseBody` annotation to the endpoint like this:

```
@GetMapping("/users")
@ResponseBody
public List<User> getUsers() {
    return service.getUsers();
}
```

Another option would be to implement the REST endpoints in a separate class annotated with `@RestController`.

Comment: Hi Mar-Z, thanks for the info. Adding the annotation @ResponseBody worked. But I didn't understand the other option. Do you mean I should create another class similar to my current controller class which I gave and in that I should write the code for the Rest api's?

Comment: Yes. To separate both types of controllers. Personally I prefer this.